# UICollectionView is never called with JSQMessagesCollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using the [https://www.raywenderlich.com/122148/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat](http://Firebase%20Messaging%20Tutorial) and I have reached "Creating Messages" portion and my collection view seems to never have been called. I had to take out all the override statement before the collection view functions because I was getting errors with them. I have tried reloading the collection view with

```
 self.collectionView!.reload()
```

Any ideas?
Here is my code:

```
Created by Ari on 7/19/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Logical Nonsense LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController
class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController  {
var messages = [JSQMessage]()
    var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!


      var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            self.collectionView!.reloadData()
          print("hi")
        title = "ChatChat"
        setupBubbles()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        addMessage(id: "foo", text: "Hey person!")
        // messages sent from local sender
        addMessage(id: senderId, text: "Yo!")
        addMessage(id: senderId, text: "I like turtles!")
        print("hi")

        // animates the receiving of a new message on the view
        finishReceivingMessage()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            self.collectionView!.reloadData()
        // messages from someone else
        addMessage(id: "foo", text: "Hey person!")
        // messages sent from local sender
        addMessage(id: senderId, text: "Yo!")
        addMessage(id: senderId, text: "I like turtles!")
        print("hi")
        // animates the receiving of a new message on the view
        finishReceivingMessage()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


   func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                                 messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
        return messages[indexPath.item]
    }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
    }
 func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
        let message = messages[indexPath.item] // 1
        if message.senderId == senderId { // 2
            return outgoingBubbleImageView
        } else { // 3
            return incomingBubbleImageView
        }
    }
 func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                                 avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
        return nil
    }
    func addMessage(id: String, text: String) {
        print(text)
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: "", text: text)
        messages.append(message!)
       self.collectionView!.reloadData()
    }
    private func setupBubbles() {
        let factory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
        outgoingBubbleImageView = factory?.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(
            with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlue())
        incomingBubbleImageView = factory?.incomingMessagesBubbleImage(
            with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGray())
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }

    */


}
```

Comment: try to reload collectionview  in main thread

Comment: maybe you need to have `collectionView.delegate = self` and `collectionView.dataSource = self` ? And also, you need the `override` infront of the delegate and datasource functions

Comment: swift gives me the error "method does not override any method from its superclass with I override the delegate and data source functions though @Tj3n

Comment: What function should I do that in? I tried adding "OperationQueue.main().addOperation({ () -> Void in
            self.collectionView!.reloadData()
        })  " at the end of addmessage and it didn't help. @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: `  func addMessage(id: String, text: String) {
        print(text)
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: "", text: text)
        messages.append(message!)
        OperationQueue.main().addOperation({ () -> Void in
                self.finishReceivingMessage()
        })
      
        
    } ` <- still not working out @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: `func addMessage(id: String, text: String) { print(text) let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: "", text: text) messages.append(message!) self.finishReceivingMessage()  }`

Comment: func addMessage(id: String, text: String) {
    print(text)
    
    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: "", text: text)
     messages.append(message!)
   
 
    self.finishReceivingMessage()
    
 } ------ still not working out @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: It's weird, im also using `JSQMessagesViewController ` in my project and if i dont use `override` keyword infront of delegate function it immediately give me error

Comment: Oh that is so weird. Just to specify by delegate method you mean all methods  that are for the collection view that  include  JSQMessagesViewController? @Tj3n

Comment: yes, all the dataSource and delegate function of mine needed that, a lot of similar code with yours btw